# Command doesn't work from a .cmd file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

This command works in a terminal, but if I save it in a `.cmd`, it doesn't show size in Mb :

```
For %%_ in ("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb") DO @(Set /a size= %%~z_ / 1048576 &Echo. Mb    %computerName% _ %%~nxt_)>>D:\out.txt
```

Why is this?

Comment: `set /a` is one of the few commands that behave differently on command line and in batch files. The result is only shown in command prompt. Without messing with [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028): `... &call Echo.%%size%% Mb    %computerName% _ %%~nxt_)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **`%size%`** after **`echo.`**
Since size is the variable which holds the size of the file

```bat
For %%_ in ("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb") DO @(Set /a size=%%~z_ / 1048576 & Echo.%size% Mb    %computerName% _ %%~nxt_)>>d:\out.txt
```

Comment: The output of the `set /a` will be echoed, not exactly need **`% var%`**, **[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpeR2.png)**